# previous and next elements from a map of sets

Tags: java

I have a map that look like this:

```
Map <Set<String>,Set<Integer>> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<Set<String>, Set<Integer>>();
```

I need to iterate over it but while I iterate I need to keep track of next and previous entries and do some operation on them. 
Something like this but this piece of code is not correct and I can't seem to figure out how to get the value of the key:

```
String previous = null;

                for (Entry<Set<String>, Set<Integer>> entry : nnpMap.entrySet()){


                    for (Iterator<String> i = entry.getKey().iterator(); i.hasNext();){
                        int nnpStartIndex;
                        int nnpEndIndex;

                        String element = i.next();

                        if (previous == null){
                            previous = element;
                        }
```

Comment: A Map.Entry doesn't have any entrySet() method. It has a getKey(), which returns the key of the entry (a Set<String> in this case), and a getValue(), which returns the value of the entry (a Set<Integer> in this case). Also, you're also initializing `previous` if it's null. So previous will always be the first element of the first key of the map.

Comment: Also they are not returned in any particular order. So operating on previous and next seems random. But I guess you are aware of that

Comment: `for (Entry<Set<String>, Set<Integer>> entry : nnpMap.entrySet()){
` but it should be `for (Entry<Set<String>, Set<Integer>> entry : myMap.entrySet()){`

Comment: @efekctive, since this map is a `LinkedHashMap`, an order for the elements is defined.

Comment: Since we don’t know the type/s of the inner sets, maybe there isn’t an order defined for their elements, though.

Comment: then why do you need Map to begin with if it will always be linked?

Comment: Somebody later on changes linkedhashmap for some other map and you guys have a bug

Answer (score 0):

The Entry object has getKey and getValue pairs which you can use to find the key and value objects of the entry. 
See javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html

Comment: I got that. My main issue is getting the previous and next element from the map.

Comment: There is no defined order for elements in a map. You might want to use some other data structure to store the keys in the order you want. If you really desperately wanted to do something like this, you could use the iterator over the entryset to find the next value

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as getting the next element from an iterator. Well, there is, but by doing that, you are making it the current element. So the solution is to keep track of the *two* previous elements and pretend that the previous element is the current one and the current one is the next:

```
    String previous = null;
    String current = null;
    for (Set<String> key : myMap.keySet()) {
        for (String next : key) {
            if (current != null) {
                doSomeOperation(previous, current, next);
            }
            previous = current;
            current = next;
        }
    }
    if (current != null) { // if all sets were empty, current is still null
        doSomeOperation(previous, current, null);
    }
```

Now, if I fill `myMap` like this:

```
    myMap.put(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b")), null);
    myMap.put(new HashSet<String>(), null); // empty set
    myMap.put(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("c", "q", "x")), null);
```

— then the calls to `doSomeOperation()` will be:

```
doSomeOperation(null, "a", "b")
doSomeOperation("a", "b", "q")
doSomeOperation("b", "q", "c")
doSomeOperation("q", "c", "x")
doSomeOperation("c", "x", null)
```

You will notice, as discussed in the comments, that since I have used a `HashSet` for the inner sets, their elements may come in an order that is neither insertion order nor alphabetical order.